# Pretty print - XML single record in Spark / Scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing

I am getting XML data in a single record. We have a built-in XML parser capability but have to supply the XML file in a indented / beautified way.

I am new to Spark and Scala. So any inputs on how to beautify / indent / pretty print an XML file in spark / scala would be helpful

**Sample Input :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><con:REQUEST xmlns:con="http://sample.com/"><Student><StudentID>100234</StudentID><Gender>Male</Gender><Surname>Robert</Surname><Firstname>Mathews</Firstname></Student></con:REQUEST></con:REQUEST>
```

**Expected Output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:REQUEST xmlns:con="http://sample.com/">
   <Student>
      <StudentID>100234</StudentID>
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <Surname>Robert</Surname>
      <Firstname>Mathews</Firstname>
   </Student>
</con:REQUEST>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val myxml =<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><con:REQUEST xmlns:con="http://sample.com/"><Student><StudentID>100234</StudentID><Gender>Male</Gender><Surname>Robert</Surname><Firstname>Mathews</Firstname></Student></con:REQUEST></con:REQUEST>
```

convert above in to `scala.xml.Elem` I am leaving it to you. 
There is a `PrettyPrinter` class in scala see this example  [scala cook book](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-xml-pretty-printing-human-readable-format)

```
val prettyPrinter = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 4)
val myxmlprettyprinted = prettyPrinter.format(myxml)
println(myxmlprettyprinted)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Ram . You have made my day. But this is not accepting the parent XML tags <?xml .....>. Any idea on how to remove it before supplying the rest of the XML data to the pretty printer ?

Comment: As I mentioned you need to covert that to xml document object not string Google for it